# No audio device detected on new sound card

Tags: windows-xp, audio, sound-card

I bought a new sound card because my built in sound card did not function. When I open YouTube, Media Player or anything that can create a sound my computer will hang up and sometimes when I start my computer it will hang when the Windows XP sound will activate.

Update:
My computer has no audio.  It says NO AUDIO DEVICE. I already installed Realtek AC97 and Realtek High Definition Audio Driver and I also pasted stream.dll to the Windows and system32 folders and I restarted my computer but it still says NO AUDIO DEVICE. Please help me.  Thanks

Comment: You should mention what sound card you bought. I would also like to add that it's entirely possible to have 2 soundcards working at the same time (onboard + sound card), at least when they're different brands and drivers.

Comment: ...but did you install the *RIGHT* AC97 drivers?  It turns out that AC97 is a very broad standard.  It's like how the term "energy-saving" can be used by a refrigerator or a washing machine.  Well, almost...  AC97 is a little more specific, so it's like how the term "energy saving" can be used by a refrigerator or a freezer.  But AC97 is not a specification that is really specific enough for driver co-compatibility.  What this means is that drivers for one AC97 chipset might not work for another AC97 chipset.  I don't know if even "Realtek AC97" is specific enough; I actually suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the on-board sound in you BIOS?

Windows may still be seeing the on-board sound chip as well as the add-in card and be getting confused.

Before disabling it in the BIOS you should uninstall any drivers you have for the on-board chip.

1. Open Device Manager, find the on-board chip entry, right-click and select Uninstall
2. Look in "Add or Remove Programs" and uninstall any drivers or software related to the on-board chip

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible things going wrong here:

1. The on-board sound is still enabled
2. The old on-board sound drivers are still installed
3. Your drivers for the new card aren't updated.

The first thing you need to check is your BIOS.  Make sure the on-board sound is disabled.  After you've done that and booted into Windows, go into the Device manager and verify the only sound card Windows sees is your new card.

After you've confirmed that Windows sees only your new sound card, go to the manufacturer's website and see if there are updated drivers.  If so, download and install them, then reboot and see if that takes care of the problem.  If not, and you're still seeing a hang, there may be something else wrong with the motherboard itself, which could be causing the on-board sound not to function as well as the hangs you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try this:

1. Start -> Run -> type services.msc -> enter
2. Look for "Windows Audio" in the list, if its stopped then this is your problem, it its not then look elsewhere
3. Right click "Windows Audio" -> Properties -> Change to Automatic -> OK
4. Now restart your computer

This worked for me, goodluck