# No audio device detected

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound card problem, no audio device detected](https://superuser.com/questions/148437/sound-card-problem-no-audio-device-detected)

My computer has no audio.  It says NO AUDIO DEVICE. I already installed Realtek AC97 and Realtek High Definition Audio Driver and I also pasted stream.dll to the Windows and system32 folders and I restarted my computer but it still says `No Audio Device`. Please help me.  Thanks

Comment: Is this the same PC from http://superuser.com/questions/148437/sound-card-problem?

Comment: looks like the same basic question.  i've added this text into the other question; closing this as duplicate.  @Paul: please don't doublepost; if you have further details to add to your earlier question, use the *edit* link on the post to add them.